Building a Image by using kaniko and trying to push to docker regsitry
Action Point : I have to build the image and push to docker registry with the help Kaniko executor.
I am using self hosted github runner.
Steps: First I tried to set up docker configuration

name: Set up Docker Configuration
env:
DOCKER_CONFIG_JSON: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_CONFIG_JSON }}
run: |
mkdir -p ${{ github.workspace }}/.docker
echo -n "$DOCKER_CONFIG_JSON" > ${{ github.workspace }}/.docker/config.json

name: Build and push alertmanager image to aws registry
run: |
pwd
ls -ltr
docker run --rm 
-v ${{ github.workspace }}:/workspace 
-v pwd/config.json:/kaniko/.docker/config.json:ro 
gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:latest 
--context=/workspace 
--dockerfile=/workspace/alertmanager/Dockerfile 
--destination=xyz/dsc/alertmanager:1.0



so when I am trying to build the image I am getting this error : error checking push permissions -- make sure you entered the correct tag name, and that you are authenticated correctly, and try again: checking push permission for "xyz/abc/alertmanager:1.0": creating push check transport for xyz failed: Get "https://xyz/v2/": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority


Just add the --skip-tls-verify option.
